# the function is not returning any value

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

the problem is -- Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

Given a list of ints, return True if the array contains a 3 next to a 3 somewhere.

```py
def has_33(list):
    for i in list:
        if (i==3 and (i+1)==3):
            return True
        else:
            pass
has_33([3, 3, 3])
```

Comment: `i` is not the index. Read on Python `for` loops.

Comment: When `i == 3`, `i+1 == 4`. They can't both be 3.

Comment: 4 will always be different than 3. Therefore your function branch on else and pass leading to None returned. You are not comparing next element, you are incrementing your current item

Answer (score 2):

`i+1` is not the next element of the list, it adds 1 to the current element of the list.

You need to loop over the list indexes, not the values.

```
def has_33(list):
    for i in range(len(list)-1):
        if list[i] == 3 and list[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Or you can loop over pairs of elements using `zip()`.

```
def has_33(list):
    for current, next in zip(list, list[1:]):
        if current == 3 == next:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_33(list):
    previous = None 
    for i in list:
        if previous is None:
            previous = i
        elif previous == 3 and i == 3:
            return True 
        else:
            previous = i
    return False 
print(has_33([1, 3, 3]))
```

Less clean than Barmar answer (not pythonic) but you could also store the previous value to compare it with the next one

Answer (score 0):

You can store the current number in a variable so it compared with the next number in the next iteration:

```
def has_33(lst):
    last = None
    for i in lst:
        if i == last == 3:
            return True
        last = i
    return False
```

You can also use `itertools.pairwise` to iterate through the list by pairs of adjacent values:

```
from itertools import pairwise

def has_33(lst):
    return any(a == b == 3 for a, b in pairwise(lst))
```

Comment: Or just `return (3, 3) in pairwise(lst)`

Answer (score 0):

An iterator solution, repeatedly finding the next 3 and checking the following element.

```
def has_33(lst):
    it = iter(lst)
    while 3 in it:
        if next(it, None) == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `enumerate` for next value and compare the current value

Code:

```
def has_33(ls):
    for i,v in enumerate(ls[:-1]):
        if v == 3 and ls[i+1] == 3:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: good answer, make return `False` instead of `false`.

Comment: return false has wrong indentation. and you get an out of range or?

Comment: In python we do not have `false` we have `False`(with capital 'F')

Comment: @MarcoF. No, we don't get an `IndexError` due to an other error in the code. The function will return after the first comparison. This means that something like `has_33([4, 3 ,3])` will give back `False`. This function wasn't tested by the author or by whoever said "good answer".

Comment: @Matthias I have checked it again. With your input there is no error. But with has_33([3, 0 ,3]) I get an IndexError.

Answer (score -1):

The `i` goes from 1 to `len(list)-1` so that we can compare the current and next values. After comparison, the list value is set to -1 just for reference.

```py
def has_33(lst):
    for i in range(0, len(lst)-1):
        if (lst[i]==3 and lst[i+1]==3):
            return True
        else:
            pass
        lst[i]=-1
    return False 

l=[3,3,0]        
k=has_33(l)
print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**